# how to implement {REQUEST_FILENAME} in web.config - httpErrors

Tags: iis, web-config

I am looking to implement a querystring of my error page, the page originally requested. but unfortunately I do not find how.
Thank you for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />      
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />                
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />

        <error statusCode="401" path="/error.aspx?type=401&page={REQUEST_FILENAME}" responseMode="Redirect" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="/error.aspx?type=403&page={REQUEST_FILENAME}" responseMode="Redirect" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/error.aspx?type=404&page={REQUEST_FILENAME}" responseMode="Redirect" />                
        <error statusCode="500" path="/error.aspx?type=500&page={REQUEST_FILENAME}" responseMode="Redirect" />
      </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As far as I know it cannot be implemented in web.config because the server variable {REQUEST_FILENAME} is not supported by error page.

Comment: @samwu, yes that's what i could see, but maybe there is another method to get this information ^^